# JAVA regular expression with space

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with the following expression:

```
String REGEX_Miasto_Dwu_Czlonowe="\D+\s\D+";

Pattern pat_Miasto = Pattern.compile(REGEX_Miasto_Dwu_Czlonowe);
Matcher mat_Miasto_Dwu_Czlonowe = pat_Miasto.matcher(adres);
```

Because the above pattern matches

```
"80-227 GDAŃSK                              DOSTUDZIENKI 666";
 "83000  PRUSZCZ GDANSKI                     UL. TYSIACLECIA 666";
```

But it only should match this expression : `"PRUSZCZ GDANSKI UL. TYSIACLECIA 666";`

THX for help.

Comment: Why should it only match that one?

Comment: @user3428215: I edited your question to improve formatting. However I am not sure whether `"GDAŃSK DOSTUDZIENKI 666"; "PRUSZCZ GDANSKI UL. TYSIACLECIA 666"` should rather be `"GDAŃSK DOSTUDZIENKI 666"` and `"PRUSZCZ GDANSKI UL. TYSIACLECIA 666"`.

Answer (score 0):

You got some problems in your regexp.

1. first you have to change all backslashes to double backslashes but if you have matches it coulde be a copy and paste error
2. \D matches non-digits. Was this your intention?

   \D+\s\D+

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/gxDeAIGAyQFqAZGX)

Therefore you match **some non digits** followed by **one space** followed by **some non digits**.

I think it is more or less by incident that your expression matches.

This could be a solution for your regexp:

```
^\d+\D+\d+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/0RE0u48AD7YLuZm1)

If you want to match your second line as a **literal**, so that only this line matches you could use:

```
Matcher.quoteReplacement(String s)
```

to build this kind of expression from a simple String. All control characters are well escaped.

Comment: heehe i have used this page. but i have problem with my REGEX_Miasto_Dwu_Czlonowe

becouse this REGEX matches to 

"80-227 GDAŃSK                              DOSTUDZIENKI 666";
"83000  PRUSZCZ GDANSKI                     UL. TYSIACLECIA 666"; 

but i need correct REGEX, which matches only to expression :
"83000  PRUSZCZ GDANSKI                     UL. TYSIACLECIA 666"; 


P.S. Sorry for my english

Comment: Updated my answer to build a regexp for your second line as a literal.

Comment: In your question the match is without the heading digits. So what is right?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches any number of non-digit `\D+`  a space `\s` then any number of non-digit. So it matches the first string:

```
80-227 GDAŃSK                              DOSTUDZIENKI 666
//    ^__________\D+_________^^____________\D+_________^
//                           |
//                         a space
```

I guess you want:

```
[^\s\d]+\s[^\s\d]+
```

Any number of non-space/non digit, a space then any number of non-space/non-digit.